# DOE for evaluating a factor with more than 2 levels

Tags: r, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I am new to designing experiments. I like the simplicity of 2-level, fractional factorial designs for screening what factors and interactions are important. However, I often conduct competitive analysis where there are three or more products to evaluate. All of the other factors can be made 2-level. What's the best way to structure an experiment in this case and why?

One thought is I could run 2-level fractional factorial experiments for each product, but this seems inefficient.

I also saw a reference on the nist site to running three-level designs from using two, two-level factors:

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri33a.htm

Comment: One idea is to use computer-generated optimal design.  R has multiple packages helping with this, see  https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=ExperimentalDesign

Comment: Ok, I'll read through the packages and see if I can find one relevant to what I'm doing. Are there any you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the approach from the link you gave, or you can use some method for algorithmic design.  One approach using the R package `planor` (on CRAN) is given in [Fractional Factorial design for 3 factorial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314673/fractional-factorial-design-for-3-factorial/316958#316958), here I will exemplify use of the R package `AlgDesign` (on CRAN).  `AlgDesign` also have some functions for evaluating given designs, you can use them with a design made "by hand", to compare with the algorithmically generated designs.  You say you have one product factor with three (or more) levels, the other variables are numerical variables with two levels each.  I will ask for a half fraction:

```r
library(AlgDesign)

Cand  <-  gen.factorial( levels=c(3, rep(2, 6)),
                        factors=1)

ex2Des  <-  optFederov( ~ (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7)^2,
                       data=Cand,
                       nTrials = 3*2^5 ,  # A half fraction
                       approximate=TRUE,
                       criterion="D",
                       evaluateI=TRUE,
                       maxIteration=1000)

eval.design(~ (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7)^2,
            ex2Des$design,
            confounding=TRUE)
    $confounding
               [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]
(Intercept) -1.0000  0.4340  0.4359  0.0390  0.0225 -0.0898 -0.1459  0.0208
X12          0.9853 -1.0000 -0.4193 -0.0349 -0.0183  0.0886  0.1392 -0.0070
.
.
.
X6:X7        0.0367  0.0431 -0.0307 -1.0000

$determinant
[1] 0.5076138

$A
[1] 3.380504

$diagonality
[1] 0.821

$gmean.variances
[1] 2.534994
```

The above gives an unblocked design.  With so many observations it could be an advantage to use a blocked design, code given below:

```r
ex2BlockDes  <-  optBlock( ~ (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7)^2,
                          withinData=Cand,
                          blocksizes=rep(12, 8),
                          nRepeats=100,
                          criterion="D")

eval.blockdesign(  ~ (X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7)^2,
                 ex2BlockDes$design,
                 blocksizes=rep(12, 8),
                 confounding=TRUE)
```

(output not given here).  `AlgDesign` is a very flexible package, and before using it you will want to read its vignette:

```r
vignette("AlgDesign")
```

Note that you should try other criteria than "D", especially for the blocked design.

Comment: how do you come up with nTrials = 3*2^5 ?

Comment: @Ben: Look at the definition (in code) of `Cand`, it a full factorial $3\cdot 2^6$, which needs 192 observations (check `NROW(Cand)` ).  `nTrials = 3*2^5` then defines a half-fraction, as explained in the code

Comment: alright, thank you!

Comment: When there was one factor with three levels and two with two levels, how would I calculate the trials then?

Comment: @Ben: For a start, see my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596056/fractional-factorial-design-when-some-factors-have-more-than-2-levels/596897#596897

Comment: @Ben: for a half-fraction of a $2^2\cdot 3$ design, following the approach linked above, you will find that a regular fraction is not possible. The reasons are number-theoretical, just use dividability ...